# Game Engine Texture errors

Tags: texturing, game-engine, shaders

Hi I have a similar problem with texture as other Blender user **BUT the difference is that all the solutions posted here on the website**(blender beta) are not solving my issue..

(**Picture 1**)  I build a game in Blender (** built & Works in Blender 2.57 only)** and **textures were displaying at first** but since 2015 January the engine started to behave strange..[image: Texture displaying]

(**Picture 2**) Each time I load the Game this message pops up **"Texface Conversion problem (see error in console)"**[image: Error message]

(**Picture 3**) Even after trying the solution you posted... the Game still **looks Black in Texture Mode** and **Total white in Game mode** (after presing **P**)[image: Picture 3][image]

In the MULTEXTURE Mode the textures appear...see picture below
(Picture 4)[image]

**Lastly.. I only use BLender 2.57 because Latest Versions give me more ERRORS* for example Animations stop working during GAME RUN time*

Comment: How can I upload my Game Blend file...? cant find or see uploading link on the site....

Comment: Uploading blend files - http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/658/including-a-blend-file

Comment: This is the Game Link :  http://www.filedropper.com/mysticalgamematerial3

Comment: " Hi I have a similar problem with texture as other Blender user" which other user? Also, what problem?

Comment: @KhayaKunene is there a specific reason you can't upgrade to 2.74? this may be a bug that was fixed since you're problem started. "Texface Conversion problem (see error in console)" tells me this is probably the case.

Comment: Ola Radish..I use & download the latest blender version all the time, for example all my 3d animation, modelling are done on the new blender version(2.74)....but the game give me ERRORS..., the game animation in blender 2.6 or 2.7  does not play fully...it stops responding & get corrupted. (Textures & animation get corrupted in 2.6/2.7). Pls download the GAME from the LINK...u will see what I mean.